# MS access 2010 restriciting varchar

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am writing a simple database and I want to restrict one Varchar variable to few values, I got this:

```
PaymentMode VARCHAR (32),

CONSTRAINT chk_PaymentMode 
CHECK (PaymentMode IN 
  ('Daily', 'Weekly, 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))
```

But it comes out with `"Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause."` and I got no idea of how to solve this, please help guys.

Comment: Why not use a lookup table with a foreign key constraint?

Comment: What will be the easiest way? Sorry, but I am very newbish in SQL and this was supposed to be my first easy project, so I got no idea how to do it in the way you mentioned. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing single-quote after 'Weekly'

Since you are unable to get this to work, I am providing code that will create a new table and place the constraint on it, displaying results at each step. Please: (1) add a new module to your Access database, then (2) paste the following code into that module, the (3) place the curser anywhere within the Function, then (4) Press F5. When it is finished, then post all the text found in the 'Immediate' window.

```
Function Test_Constraint()
Dim strSQL      As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database

Debug.Print "**** START TEST ****"
On Error Resume Next
Set dbs = CurrentDb
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Error on Set dbs: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
Err.Clear

strSQL = "CREATE TABLE Temp_Payment (StudentID INT, StudentName VARCHAR (32), PaymentID INT, PaymentMode VARCHAR (32), PRIMARY KEY (PaymentID))"
Debug.Print "Create Table SQL: " & strSQL
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Error on Create Table: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
Err.Clear

strSQL = "ALTER TABLE Temp_Payment DROP CONSTRAINT chk_Temp_PaymentMode ;"
Debug.Print "DROP Constraint SQL: " & strSQL
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Error on DROP Constraint: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & strSQL
Err.Clear

strSQL = "ALTER TABLE Temp_Payment ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Temp_PaymentMode CHECK (PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))"
Debug.Print "ADD Constraint SQL: " & strSQL
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Error on ADD Constraint: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & strSQL
Err.Clear

Debug.Print "**** END TEST ****"
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Lets define your environment; I assume you are using SQL Server based upon the the fact your syntax will not work in Access. Is that correct? 
How about running the following in SQL Server and see what happens:
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.AAAA', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.AAAA;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.AAAA
    (ID int PRIMARY KEY, PaymentMode varchar (32))
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.AAAA ADD CONSTRAINT chk_PaymentMode
    CHECK (PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))

Comment: I am using MS Access, I am creating queries which then I view in SQL and then write the code. Therefore should I just use "GO ALTER TABLE dbo.AAAA ADD CONSTRAINT chk_PaymentMode CHECK (PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly')) "?

Comment: Is your table defined in Access, or is it defined in SQL Server and linked like ODBC in Access? If defined in Access, you need a different approach. If defined in SQL Server, you would use the 'Alter Table' (The 'GO' is for the previous command, so don't include'); If you currently have a constraint on that table, it must be deleted first, but give it a try and see.

Comment: All I write is in Access and I didn't want to use SQL Server, so I don't over complicate it and it's for my teacher, as he will use it in Access only. In the progress to build other tables I had to Alter them aftewards to add foreign keys and columns, everything went smooth in altering beside the one we are on about giving me the very same reason :(

Comment: OK, in Access, assuming there is no existing constraint, I just ran the following and it works correctly; substitue your table name, field name:
    strSQL = "ALTER TABLE tblShoeCreditCard ADD CONSTRAINT LimitRule " _
     & " CHECK (chk_PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL

Comment: ALTER TABLE Payment
ADD CONSTRAINT PaymentMode CHECK (chk_PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))" CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL

Was that right? Table is called Payment and field name is PaymentMode, I tried to do it in few different ways but it's not working either way... I am sorry, I probably give you a headache :(

Comment: Yes, that is the table & field - CHANGE TO YOUR environment... Please post EXACTLY the code you are trying to run in VBA. What Error message do you get? What line do you get the error on?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Payment
(
StudentID INT,
StudentName VARCHAR (32),
PaymentID INT,
PaymentMode VARCHAR (32),
ReciptID INT,

PRIMARY KEY (PaymentID),
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID, StudentName) REFERENCES StudentINFO(StudentID, StudentName),
FOREIGN KEY (ReciptID) REFERENCES Recipt(ReciptID)
)

Table that is built and it's fine.

ALTER TABLE Payment ADD CONSTRAINT PaymentMode CHECK (chk_PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))

This is the code I try to run, Acces points "CHECK" and says "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause." Thank you for your help and sorry for me :(

Comment: I see where the problem is... the SQL I provided earlier to set the constraint was based on a table I already had, so there is a wrong spelling. Change the string 'chk_PaymentMode' to remove the leading 'chk_'. That is the name of the field in your table.  Sad to say, but if you go back to the original post where I said there was a single-quote missing, that is the same syntax as now (except I would revert to the "ORIGINAL + quote" so the FK name is more meaningful.

Comment: "ALTER TABLE Payment
ADD CONSTRAINT PaymentMode CHECK (PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))"
It still gives the same error with check, maybe there is another way of putting restriction of input values on varchar? :)

Comment: This has to be simple!  I am running the exact syntax you now have! What exactly is the error message and code?
Yes, there are alternate methods. (1) Go into table design  for that field and for "Validation Rule" enter "Daily" or "Weekly"... (2) Create a table of allowable values and enforce referential integrity on that column.

Comment: I wrote the error few times already, it's "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause." and points "CHECK" as an error.

Comment: Please check your Access table column Payment.PaymentMode and tell me: (1) What is the Data Type (I hope it's TEXT); (2) What is the Field Size (not that it should matter. Here are four things I just did, any will generate that error message: (a) removed a comma between values; (b) removed a single-quote from around any value; (c) removed one of the closing ')'; (d) misspelled PaymentMode. Since I can't easily show code in this comment, I am going to provide another ANSWER with code for you to run on about 5 minutes.

Comment: Please look above at my answer. I have added code for you to test with.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try it in a second, 1) Data Type is TEXT. 2) Field Size is 32.

Comment: **** START TEST ****
Create Table SQL: CREATE TABLE Temp_Payment (StudentID INT, StudentName VARCHAR (32), PaymentID INT, PaymentMode VARCHAR (32), PRIMARY KEY (PaymentID))
DROP Constraint SQL: ALTER TABLE Temp_Payment DROP CONSTRAINT chk_Temp_PaymentMode ;
Error on DROP Constraint: -2147467259   CHECK constraint 'chk_Temp_PaymentMode' does not exist.
ALTER TABLE Temp_Payment DROP CONSTRAINT chk_Temp_PaymentMode ;
ADD Constraint SQL: ALTER TABLE Temp_Payment ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Temp_PaymentMode CHECK (PaymentMode IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Every Six Months', 'Yearly'))
**** END TEST ***

Comment: That's what I got, thank you very much for your time and help! :) Ms Access is such a pain, now I can't even build other tables due to "No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table". However it did build two tables with few foreign keys, now it can't. I am thinking of getting sql server.

Comment: Regarding "now I can't even build other tables due to "No unique index found", it is simple to add a primary key, you can even do that manually. And SQL Server is a good sized leap depending on if you are DAO, how much code, etc.

Comment: Yes I know, but I can't do it as a code due to that error, I've read that you have to do something on entity relationships to get it working, but I got no idea how.

Comment: I'm afraid that without seeing your existing table structures, relationships, etc. that this could be a nightmare trying to go back and forth on. If you want to pursue, then you would need to provide VERY specific issues and full details of current structure.

Comment: Oh it's all fine now, I mean you helped me very much with getting the restrictions on the PaymentMode. I will take care of the rest, even if I'll have to build the tables without the use of sql. Thank you very much! :)